# Issue with image upload using Retrofit

Tags: retrofit2, image-uploading

I'm using retrofit to upload images on server, image are uploading successfully, but without extension.
Means only image name is uploading to database, extension is not there.
So image became useless for me.
please provide help.
here is my method in interface->

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/webservices/AssessorAssetsUpload.php")
        Call<ImageModel> uploadImage(
            @Field("name")String pictype,
            @Field("type")String uploadtype,
            @Field("accesser_id")String asses_id,
            @Field("paper_schedule_id")String paper_id,
            @Field("imagefile")String image
        );


    my activity code->

        String image=imagetoString();

            RetrofitInterface retrofit=ApiClient.getApiClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<ImageModel> call=retrofit.uploadImage(imageName,"image",assessor_id,paperId,image);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ImageModel> call, Response<ImageModel> response) {
                    System.out.println(response.body().getStatus()+" "+response.body().getMsg()+" "+response.body().getUrl());

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ImageModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

    private String imagetoString(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
    byte[] bytes=stream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We use Multipart instead of formurlencoded in case of any multimedia object.

     @Multipart
        @POST("/webservices/AssessorAssetsUpload.php")
        Call<ImageModel> uploadImage(
            @Part("name")RequestBody pictype,
            @Part("type")RequestBody uploadtype,
            @Part("accesser_id")RequestBody asses_id,
            @Part("paper_schedule_id")RequestBody paper_id,
            @Part("imagefile")MultipartBody.Part image
        );


    MultipartBody.Part image=imagetoPart();

            RetrofitInterface retrofit=ApiClient.getApiClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<ImageModel> call=retrofit.uploadImage(
                getTextRequest("imageName"),
                getTextRequest("image"),
                getTextRequest("assessor_id"),
                getTextRequest("paperId"),
                image
                );

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ImageModel> call, Response<ImageModel> response) {
                    System.out.println(response.body().getStatus()+" "+response.body().getMsg()+" "+response.body().getUrl());

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ImageModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

    private String imagetoPart(){

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Image Path");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
        byte[] bytes=stream.toByteArray();
        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), bytes);
        MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("name", "name", reqFile);

        return part;
    }

 private RequestBody getTextRequest(String body) {

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), body);

        return requestBody;
    }
```

We need to convert the fields into request body and image into a multipart body to send it as a multipart request. This will do your work.